# Is this the right way to have multiple levels unlocked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Working on a game for iOS with multiple levels. I've been playing around and this is what I've come up with:

To save the level:

```
-(void)gameEnded {
    _touched = YES;

    if (_touched == YES) {
        beatLevel = YES;
        NSLog(@"touched");

        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[
            [SKAction runBlock:^{

            level2Achieved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"newLevelAchieved"];
            if (beatLevel == YES) {
                level2Achieved = 2;
            }
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:level2Achieved forKey:@"newLevelAchieved"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }],
            [SKAction waitForDuration:0.5],
            [SKAction runBlock:^{

            MyScene *mainMenu = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
            [self.view presentScene:mainMenu transition:[SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.6]];

        }],
                                                   ]]];

    }
}
```

Then I imported the levels header file into my main menu (where the selection of levels 1-40 are), and set up the following code to see if or if not the next level has been selected:

```
//set up levelAchieved:
level2Achieved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"newLevelAchieved"];
```

Plus an if statement when the user goes to tap on the level to see if it's been unlocked or not:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"lv2"] && level2Achieved == 2) {
    testScene2 *firstLevel = [[testScene2 alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:firstLevel transition:[SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] duration:0.5]];
}
```

**This worked for me but before I do it for the next 38 levels, is this the right way to do it? AND do I have write in a**

```
//set up levelAchieved:
levelXAchieved = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"newLevelAchieved"];
```

**for each new level? 
Is there a way to do this with an NSMutableArray?** Or a way to override the NSUserDefaults without the program forgetting that the previous level was unlocked aswell??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312465/creating-levels-in-an-ios-sprite-kit-game/23316664?noredirect=1#23316664 it might help you out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try making an `NSMutableArray` and adding a value to it each time the player achieves a new level. i.e. an NSString then check if NSString isEqual to a value before the player clicks that level?